# Error loading type library/DLL (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ms-office, office-interop, office-2013

I'm trying to create an Excel document via C#. When I run the application, it gives the following error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due
>   to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

[image]

It was working fine before I've upgraded **Visual Studio from 2010 to 2012**. I've also upgraded **Office from 2010 to 2013**.

- There are no errors/warnings at output window.
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference is added

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this error for a few days . I've finally found the solution.

It occurs because I’ve installed **Office 2013** instead of Office 2010 which I was using with old version of my project. After I upgraded my Office, the project was no longer able to link Excel reference.

Even though I referenced new Excel library which is **15.0**, it didn't work.

What I did is that:

- **Delete the Excel reference** (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel). Version
  15.0, in my case.
- **Install Microsoft Excel** (whichever version you had been using. Version 2010 for me)
- **Add the Excel reference** (older one.
  Version 14.0, in my case)